# Apexchart line chart multiple line Json

Tags: php, json, charts

I have followed the Apexchart Json funtion and that works well for a single line of data in a barchart.

I have tried and created a few examples from their site and they are easy to follow and all work.

So my question.

I have a Json file (snippit below). Which I would like to create a line chart from, however unlike their site example this one will not always have the same stages.

It has 3 stages start, running and complete. But these are not always present on every day.

[
{
"The_Date": "2021-07-01",
"Stage": "Start",
"Total": 7
},
{
"The_Date": "2021-07-01",
"Stage": "Running"
"Total": 6
},
{
"The_Date": "2021-07-01",
"Stage": "Complete"
"Total": 50
},
{
"The_Date": "2021-07-02",
"Stage": "Start",
"Total": 13
},
{
"The_Date": "2021-07-02",
"Stage": "Running"
"Total": 69
},
{
"The_Date": "2021-07-03",
"Stage": "Start",
"Total": 22
},
{
"The_Date": "2021-07-03",
"Stage": "Running"
"Total": 9
},
{
"The_Date": "2021-07-03",
"Stage": "Complete"
"Total": 86
}
]

This is their example https://apexcharts.com/docs/update-charts-from-json-api-ajax/ for the Json to bar chart, I know changing the type to line works for a single set of data.

Has anyone managed to create a multiple line chart using this functionality ? If so any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit more reading, I foudn that converting my Json to include "x" and "y" as value headers and having individual elements in the Json I could add the additional data like this:

```
chart.appendSeries({
    name: 'Chart legend',
    data: response.JsonElementnamehere,
    })
```

JsonElementnamehere would be your Json element name..